# Libgdx pre-rendering Bitmap font to pixmap texture causes slow in-game rendering

Tags: libgdx, performance, scene2d

Im using libgdx scene2d to render 2d actors. Some of these actor groups originally included scene2d Label actors for rendering static text. The Labels work fine but drawing ~20 of them on the screen at once drops the frame rate by 10-15 frames, resulting in noticeably poor rendering while dragging.

I'm attempting to avoid the Labels by pre-drawing the text to textures, and rendering the textures as scene2d Image actors. I'm creating the texture using the code below. (Inspired by [Libgdx FPS drop drawing alot of text](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128042/libgdx-fps-drop-drawing-alot-of-text))

I assumed, and have read, that textures are often faster. However when I replaced the Labels with the texture, it had the same, if not worse, effect on the frame rate. Oddly, I'm not experiencing this when adding textures from a file, which makes me think I'm doing something wrong in my code. Is there a different way I should be pre-rendering these pieces of text?

```
BitmapFont font =  manager.get(baseNameFont,BitmapFont.class);
GlyphLayout gl = new GlyphLayout(font,"Test Text");

int textWidth = (int)gl.width;
int textHeight = (int)gl.height;
LOGGER.info("textHeight: {}",textHeight);
//int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
int width = textWidth;
//int height = 500;
int height = textHeight;

SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

FrameBuffer m_fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB565, width,height, false);
m_fbo.begin();
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f,1f,1f,0f);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
Matrix4 normalProjection = new Matrix4()

        .setToOrtho2D(0, 0, width,  height);
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(normalProjection);

spriteBatch.begin();

font.draw(spriteBatch,gl,0,height);


spriteBatch.end();//finish write to buffer

Pixmap pm = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height);//write frame buffer to Pixmap

m_fbo.end();

m_fbo.dispose();
m_fbo = null;
spriteBatch.dispose();

Texture texture = new Texture(pm);
textTexture = new TextureRegion(texture);
textTexture.flip(false,true);
manager.add(texture);
```

Comment: Can you show any more details about how you go about drawing your labels and when and how you are creating them?
You shouldn't see a noticable performance impact at 20 `Labels` unless they have extremely long text, thousands of Labels should run just fine even on a modest computer.

Comment: I've just been informed by another user that libgdx *does not* automatically cull actors that are outside the viewport, despite seeing multiple other comments that say it *does*. So this may actually be part of the issue. This would mean 100+ labels are being "drawn" though only 20 of them are visible in the viewport. I can't find a good tutorial on how to get the culling area from the camera frustum though.

Comment: Still, thousands of labels on or off screen shouldn't be an issue. So it would still be interesting to see how you do it, @The Shoe Shiner.

Comment: @bornander I think it would be if Libgdx had to call draw() on each of them. Label.draw() is a relatively expensive operation. The constructor you see above is all I'm doing. Libgdx handles drawing the Labels when they are added to an Actor within a Stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this slowness was my misunderstanding about Libgdx culling. Scene2d *does not* automatically cull objects outside of the view frustum. Therefore my hundreds of shapes and labels were having `draw()` called when they weren't even visible in the camera. My short term fix for this was that I test whether an object is within the frustum during `draw()`, and as soon it's not visible I call setVisible(false) which tells GDX to skip the draw. I think a more elegant solution would be to set the culling area on the stage, but I would need to adjust it as the user pans the camera. I have not tested this since I've gotten past my current performance issues, but I believe it should work.

The answer comes from [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284058/libgdx-rendering-bitmap-font-to-pixmap-texture-causes-extremely-slow-rendering/) on StackOverflow.